# Possible software missmatch (Arduino Uno)

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When trying to run the rosserial tutorials (blink for example: [http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Blink]) I receive the following error:

```
$ rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM1
[INFO] [WallTime: 1446076253.296082] ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [WallTime: 1446076253.301507] Connecting to /dev/ttyACM1 at 57600 baud
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1446076270.407976] Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino
```

I have updated rosserial to the indigo version (which I run) using the zip file availible through github [https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/tree/indigo-devel], regenerated the libraries, and retested in accordance with this very similar problem's solution [http://answers.ros.org/question/196204/unable-to-sync-with-device-arduino-uno/]. However, the problem persists.

Any ideas as to what I should try next? Any suggestions are appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220072/possible-software-missmatch-(arduino-uno)/) by [drzippiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/24943/drzippiz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2015-10-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We ran a full set of system updates for our ROS using laptop, and the problem disappeared.

---

Originally posted by [drzippiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/24943/drzippiz/) with karma: 16 on 2015-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have come across the same issue. For me, the problem was due to the use of software serial library. I changed my Uno for a Mega and used one of the hardware serial channels.

After that, we have seen the problem surface arise here and there. Normally, simply reuploading the code solved our issue. If not, we removed the build and devel folders, did a full catkin_make, rebuild the arduino scripts and re-uploaded the arduino files.

---

Originally posted by [David L-B](https://answers.ros.org/users/21974/david-l-b/) with karma: 71 on 2015-10-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [drzippiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/24943/drzippiz/) on 2015-11-04**:
Thanks! We are now seeing the roughly what you described. We just reupload whenever we nee to fix it.